# Char frequency repeating and resetting issue

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a character frequency counter based on the first letter of a word in a list of strings but the other counters would reset to 0 whenever a value would go from 0 to 1. The code looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std; 

const int MAXIMUMQUANTITY = 400;
struct program
{
int pid;
string program1;
};
struct number
{
    program list[MAXIMUMQUANTITY];
    int numberofdata;
};
int main(void)
{
number alldata;
fstream fREAD;
fREAD.open(text.txt);
int minimum;
cin >> minimum;
int maximum;
cin >> maximum;
if (!fREAD.fail()) {
    alldata.numberofdata = 0;

    while (!ws(fREAD).eof())
    {

        fREAD >> alldata.list[alldata.numberofdata].pid
            >> alldata.list[alldata.numberofdata].program1;

        string program = alldata.list[alldata.numberofdata].program1;
if (minimum <= alldata.list[alldata.numberofdata].pid){
    if (alldata.list[alldata.numberofdata].pid <= maximum){
    int freq1 = 0;
    int freq2 = 0;
    int freq3 = 0;
    int def = 0;
    switch (program[0])
    {                   
    case 'A': freq1++;
        break;
    case 'B': freq2++; 
        break;
    case 'C': freq3++; 
        break;
    default: def++;
        break;
    }
    cout << "category 1: " << freq1 << endl;
    cout << "category 2: " << freq2 << endl;
    cout << "category 3: " << freq3 << endl;
    cout << "category 4: " << def << endl;
}
}
}
}
else
cout << "invalid file" << endl;
}
```

I want the output to give something like this:

```
category 1: 1
category 2: 2
category 3: 3
category 4: 4
```

But instead I'm getting something like:

```
category 1: 1
category 2: 0
category 3: 0
category 4: 0

category 1: 0
category 2: 1
category 3: 0
category 4: 0

category 1: 0
category 2: 0
category 3: 0
category 4: 1

category 1: 0
category 2: 0
category 3: 0
category 4: 1 etc...
```

The list is duplicated whenever a value would be changed, and the changed value would follow the order that was in the list. 
For example, if the first word would start by B, the second by A, and the whole list would be 2 words long, the output would be:

```
category 1: 0
category 2: 1
category 3: 0
category 4: 0

category 1: 1
category 2: 0
category 3: 0
category 4: 0
```

Comment: You should provite a complete code hard to follow you.

Comment: Please clarify your goal. What exactly is the input? The code you posted looks like the content of a function. Maybe you did not understand how scopes work and that each time the function is called, its inner variables are reset.

Comment: Your code sets all variables to `0` and does a single increment of one of the variables. why do you expect the others should magically become non-zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your integer are in the while loop and are initialize at each loop. so you should put the

```
int freq1 = 0;
int freq2 = 0;
int freq3 = 0;
int def = 0;
```

outside to the loop.

```
int freq1 = 0;
int freq2 = 0;
int freq3 = 0;
int def = 0;
 while (!ws(fREAD).eof())
```

then your integer should not be reset to 0 every time.

now it will write the each time so you should also put the cout at the end of the while loop.